# Chain rule of a multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, differential

I was doing some exercises of the chain rule in multivariate calculus, but i saw this problem and i'm not sure where to start, if you could give me some advice.

Let $f$ differential on $(u,v)$ and $g$ a function of $(x,y)$ given $g(x,y)=f(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ compute $g_x$ and $g_y$ in terms of $f_x$ and $f_y$

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: are you sure the question is not about $g_x$ and $g_y$ in terms of $f_u$ and $f_v$?

Comment: @TonyDelgado  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $f(u,v)$ with $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, $v(x,y)=2xy$ thus

$$g_x=f_u u_x+ f_v v_x=f_u \cdot 2x+f_v \cdot2y$$

$$g_y=f_u u_y+ f_v v_y=f_u \cdot -2y+f_v \cdot2x$$